# Fit webpage to screen issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a webpage structured by sections as follows:

```
<body id="top">
  <section id="nav">

  </section>
  <div id="intro">

  </div>
  <div id="main">

  </div>
  <div id="footer">

  </div>
</body>
```

I want to stretch the `intro` section to fit the height automatically based on the browser screen height.

I've tried with CSS:

```
#intro {         
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

But for some reason the second div `main` is overlapping the `intro` section and not displaying the `main` section as it supposed to be, after the `intro` section.

What am I missing here? should I use jQuery to get the screen height first?

Comment: Why should it be after the intro section? You've absolutely positioned #intro so it is taken out of normal flow.

Comment: Can you provide the needed structure? Should it be before the intro section?

Comment: define width and height also

Comment: `absolute` positioning takes the element out of the normal layout, so the rest of your elements are not positioned relative to `#intro` anymore, and instead placed underneath it as if the `#intro` element didn't exist. (I just wanted to explain why your CSS isn't working. The correct answer would be to use `vh` as answered by Simon).

Answer (score 2):

To set your intro section to the height of the browser screen you can use `vh`

```
#intro {
 height:100vh;
}
```

vh scale with the height of the screen

Comment: Thanks for the answer Simon. It is just what I needed! Is it supported by all browsers?

Comment: This website shows the support for vh units. As you can see IE 8 and earlier don't support it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 2):

You need to set height:100% for body and html, then you should think about other elements to give them some absolute or fix position to prevent overflow, or you can use position fix

1.

```
body,html {
   height:100%
}
#otherElement {
   position: absolute       
}
```

2.

```
#intro {         
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 10/* if needed*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but I think I will try to accomplish it with height:100vh which is exactly what I needed. I'll try to check the script also to include other incompatible browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution supported in more browsers, jQuery is the way to go.

```
function resizeIntro(){
    $('#intro').height($(window).height());   
}
resizeIntro();
$(window).resize(resizeIntro);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1du9k94/1/